# how to stay app open when the user press back button

Tags: android

I want to create an app with this ability:when the user press back button.don't close app & stay in running list in settings->application manager->running
& stay in running list when user press home button too.

I like to make an app that there isn't in task manager->active application but there is in settings->application manager->running such as Viber,Tango,Gmail

Comment: Override the back button.

Comment: use a receiver and run something in background to maintain your process stays running.Override backpressed in your class to handle its click.

Comment: Use a Service or AsyncTask to do work in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it as follow:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(false);
}
```

to minimize your app use `moveTaskToBack(true);`

**NOTE:** don't write `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: moveTaskToBack(false); `true` will close the application or activity while OP has asked not to close the activity.

Comment: welcome, just to add one more thing that above code doesn't minimize the application.

Comment: but with this code app stay in task manager too & when the user press end my app will be close.  but there are many app that there aren't in task manager but are running how can I do it?

Comment: this is another question. But as per my knowledge no one can make an app that is not killed by the app manager.

Comment: Even if you write a background service to wake up your app the app manager will also kill the service.

Comment: ok I know it.but I like to make an app that there isn't in task manager->active application  but there is in settings->application manager->running such as Viber,Tango,Gmail

Comment: They show it in the running because they have background service running but the app may have closed

Answer (score 1):

Add `onBackPressed()` into your `Activity`:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     moveTaskToBack(false);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onbackpress and do the code for application to go background

Comment: how to do the code for application to go background?

Comment: moveTaskToBack I think

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197281/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-movetasktoback-method-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep your app running? If you need to process data while the user is not in your app, you need a Service:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

[Android simple service not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671102/android-simple-service-not-starting)